# Perennial cover crops in vineyard

Tags: vines, grape-vine, cover-crop

I have a small vineyard and planning to grow cover crops between the rows.

I have little experience with cover crops and first of all I'm not sure when to mow them, and if the cut crops should be removed and used to make compost or if they should be left there as kind of a green manure?

Answer (score 2):

The cover crop will compost just fine where it is while providing protection and moisture to the soil. Removing the residue is detrimental.

By perennial, you mean something like White clover? I'd just leave the clover alone and only cut any weed that pops up. The grapevines will take advantage of the additional moisture and residual nitrogen. You don't want to fertilize grapevines. It only produces more green growth.

You should also look into companions. Low shrubby and creeping herbs will help with pests and possibly with fungal diseases.

Comment: yes, white clover and a bunch of others that I don't really know the names of (sainfoin, lucerne, red clover, bird's-foot trefoil with some aid of google translate).